# Is there a way to set MaxRequestBodySize for out-of-process deployment mode similar to IISServerOptions for in-process?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, out-of-process

When I try publishing the web api and deploying on my local iis, the setting below works

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => options.MaxRequestBodySize = 12000);
```

But in the server it doesn't work. I noticed that the deployment mode in `web.config` is different between my local and the server.

In my local:

```
hostingModel="inprocess"
```

while in the server it is:

```
hostingModel="OutOfProcess"
```

The `IISServerOptions` is for `in-process`. What should be the equivalent setting of MaxRequestBodySize that I should apply for `out-of-process`?

Comment: What are your reasons to use the legacy out-of-process mode?

Comment: Does it work if you change the setting hostingModel on the server to `inprocess`?

Comment: @LexLi not sure if it is ok to use `in-process` but I got "HTTP Error 500.34 - ASP.NET Core does not support mixing hosting models" error after I change it to `in-process` and change `builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration();` to `builder.WebHost.UseIIS();`

Comment: @samwu not yet, please see my reply to Lex, the application pool configuration in the server might need to change. I will need to investigate.

Comment: That 500.34 indicates that in the same application pool you might have many ASP.NET Core web apps, which you never mentioned in the question. Can you move this web app to its own application pool so that in-process hosting mode can then work?

Comment: @Lex how iis application pool is configured is not decided by me and I don't have permission to access it as well. I think there is a script to control this and should not be modified. I think I will need to keep it out-of-process. If there isn't anything similar as `IISServerOptions` then I might need to do it in MiddleWare

Comment: @Lex I was thinking to make the settings in `web.config` but since we want the `web.config` file generation to be automatic without manual modification - I am not sure if there is a way for me to set the maximum request size in `dotnet publish` command

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.